# How to refresh a view automatically?

Tags: views, 8, theming, javascript

I have a Drupal 8 site with NodeJS.

I use the following module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/private_message_nodejs

For the installation, I followed the instructions in the documentation of the module page :

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/private-message

I created a page view and want it updated automatically.

I created a JS file in my sub theme :

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  $('.view-inbox').trigger('RefreshView');

}(jQuery));
```

But it does not work.

How to refresh a view automatically ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the [`README.md`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/private_message_nodejs/tree/README.md?h=8.x-1.x).

> ```
> ## Installation
>
> ### 1. Install Node.js
>
> Instructions on Node.js installation are not provided here, as they differ per
> system, and instructions are outside the scope of this document. Please see
> the [Node.js homepage](https://nodejs.org/en/) for more information.
>
> ### 2. Install the module
>
> Install the private_message_nodejs module as you would any Drupal module.
>
> ### 3. Install the nodeJS dependendencies
>
> On the command line, navigate to [VENDOR FOLDER]/jaypan/private-message-nodejs
> and run the following command:
>
> `npm install`
>
> ### 4. Create the Nodejs configuration
>
> Navigate to [VENDOR FOLDER]/jaypan/private-message-nodejs/config
>
> Create default.json by copying either http-example.default.json (for HTTP
> connections) or https-example.default.json (for HTTPS connections). Fill in all
> the values in the JSON file. Note that you will need to navigate to the Private
> Message settings form, and copy the Nodejs secret value, to paste into
> default.json. Note that if you are using https, you should start with port 8443,
> and if you are able to get that working, you can try other ports.
>
> ### 5. Start the app
>
> On the command line, navigate to [VENDOR FOLDER]/jaypan/private-message-nodejs
> and run the following command:
>
> `node app.js`
>
> Note: Leave this open and running, as closing the server will stop it from
> working.
>
> ### 6. Enter the URL to the node.js server in the private message configuration
>
> In the web browser, navigate to /admin/config/private_message/config. Expand the
> Private Message Nodejs settings section, and enter the URL to the node JS app.
> It should be found at [your domain]:[port you entered into configuration]. Save.
>
> ### 7. Test
>
> Open up the private message page and check that there has been some output in
> the command line, indicating that connections have been made to the Nodejs
> server.
> ```

Comment: NodeJS works very well and Private Message too. It's just that I can not refresh a page view in real time

Comment: @MPU – Ah OK. Could you please update the question to let us know how you installed everything?

Comment: It is done. Everything is in the documentation.